# mvnw permission denied error during travis build

Tags: java, linux, maven, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to build application [java-cloud-sample](https://github.com/lapots/java-cloud-sample) from `github` using `travis-ci`.

`.travis.yml` looks like this

```
language: java
sudo: true
dist: trusty
jdk: oraclejdk9
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java9-installer
before_script: 
  - chmod a+x ./mvnw
```

But when it tries to build application I get this error

```
$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ java -Xmx32m -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
$ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
javac 9
3.01s$ ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 236: ./mvnw: Permission denied
The command "eval ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 236: ./mvnw: Permission denied
The command "eval ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V " failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 236: ./mvnw: Permission denied
The command "eval ./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V " failed 3 times.
The command "./mvnw install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V" failed and exited with 126 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

I was trying to set `chmod a+x mvnw` and it did not help either. What is the problem?

Answer (score 16):

Can you try changing `before_script` to `before_install`?, as follows:

```
language: java
sudo: true
dist: trusty
jdk: oraclejdk9
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - oracle-java9-installer
before_install:
  - chmod +x mvnw
```

Comment: Please @lapots, can you mark this anwser as correct?

Comment: This looks to be an answer actually.